# Read large size xlsx file and copy all

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sax, xssf

I am trying to open a large size(>30mb) .xlsx and copy all the rows and columns(consists of >200k rows) in that sheet into a new workbook sheet. I got an error on the following code:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
XSSFWorkbook newWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

Increasing heap space does not help. After much research, i understand that a work around is either to use [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api) or XLSX2CSV.java. I just need to copy the whole data from old sheet to new sheet. Somehow after trying SAX, i am stuck as i am not sure how to get the value from old sheet to copy to new sheet. Also, empty cells are not included in the SST. i need to copy over all cells, inclusive of empty cell.

```
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // c => cell
        if(name.equals("c")) {
            //print cell reference
            System.out.print(attributes.getValue("r") + " - ");
            // Figure out if value is an index in the SST
            String cellType = attributes.getValue("t");
            System.out.println("CellType " + cellType);
            if(cellType != null && cellType.equals("s")) {
                isNextString = true;
            }else {
                isNextString = false;
            }
        }
        //Clear last content
        lastContents = "";
    }
```

I am using Java, though i can try on C#.

Comment: How is this related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74530997/230513) on the topic?

Comment: I have some sample code that reads an excel file and writes it out using streaming code - the support is limited (some formatting may be lost) - but have a look at https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader/wiki/Streaming-copy-with-SXSSF

Comment: @PJFanning i see. but i need to keep those cell format like Date or Numeric value

Comment: @trashgod my previous question is to see the xml payload before getting the elements/attributes

Comment: @PJFanning i'll try this. but do u happen to have the external library instead of pom ? my project dont use pom

Comment: The latest release is at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader/4.0.4/ - and this includes a jar

Comment: @PJFanning thank you. Any dependencies ? I already have apache poi in my prijects

Comment: the dependencies are in the pom file - https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader/4.0.4/excel-streaming-reader-4.0.4.pom

Comment: @PJFanning im still facing java heap space, but at a different line when i iterate over all the cells